# Using bash "double paren" arithmetic expansion, math fails with leading zero

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

I have a simple script that deals with hours and minutes.

If I want to calculate number of minutes since midnight having a string s `hh:mm` I tried splitting string then doing `hh * 60 + mm`

My problem is, while

```
$ (( tot = 12 * 60 + 30 ))
$ echo $tot
750
```

instead

```
$ (( tot = 09 * 60 + 30 ))
bash: ((: tot = 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

As far as I understand string `09` is not to be intended as a base 10 number.

Is there a better way than simply removing leading zeros in string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
h=09; m=30;(( tot = 10#$h * 60 + 10#$m )); echo $tot
```

The number before the  `#` is the radix (or base)
The number after the `#` must be valid for the radix
The output is always decimal
You can use a radix of *2 thru 64* (in GNU bash   4.1.5)

Note that Bash requires a leading minus sign to come before the `10#`, so if your number has one, adding the `10#` prefix directly won't work.

As noted by *enzoyib*, the old alternative of `$[expression]` is deprecated, so it is better to use the POSIX compliant `$((expr))`

```
$(( 2#1)) ==  1
$((16#F)) == 15
$((36#Z)) == 35
```

I'm not sure which 'digits' are used after `Z`

Comment: what about a litte more information about `$[10#09]` ???

Comment: I enclosed it in `hh` extraction: `hh=$[10#${hhmm%:*}]` the hell of readability! :D Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: +1, but from bash's manual page: "The old format `$[expression]` is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.". Better to use `$((expr))` that is POSIX compliant.

Comment: The *ksh* and *bash* manpages describe the digits for bases higher than 36: `0`-`9`, `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `@`, `_` (bases 36 and lower are case insensitive).

Comment: `$[ expr ]` is still supported in Bash 5.1 right now. It's not likely to _actually_ go away. (It's not the only undocumented obsolete thing that Bash still secretly supports.)

Comment: from `man bash`: `If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35` so for bases larger than 36 the digits are case-sensitive. `63#z` and `63#Z` will be different

Answer (score 5):

A leading zero on a numeric constant in shell arithmetic expressions denotes an octal constant.

Here's a portable way of deleting initial zeros:

```
h=${h#${h%%[!0]*}}; [ -n "$h" ] || h=0
```

In bash, ksh or zsh, you can [explicitly specify base 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19307/using-bash-double-paren-arithmetic-expansion-math-fails-with-leading-zero/19309#19309) with `$((10#$h))`.