# How to grep a file for a timestamp? I'm looking for the hour digits

Tags: bash, shell, grep, timestamps

I'm making a script using BASH that greps the timestamp from a file (~/logs/Server_Info.log). Specifically,  I want to pull the hour digit from the timestamp and record it onto a variable.

This is the format I used for the timestamp:

```
date +"%b-%d-%Y-%I:%M:%S %p"
```

And I used this script to pull the data:

```
#!/bin/bash
LAST_HOUR="$(( $(date +%I) - 1 ))"
SEARCH_STRING=$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-${LAST_HOUR}:")

timeval=$(grep "${SEARCH_STRING}" ~/logs/Server_Info.log)
echo "$timeval"

exit 0
```

However, whenever I execute this script, I either get two answers:

*Blank output*

-or-

*04*

which was completely wrong, because my timestamp is

```
Mar-24-2017-05:07:00 PM
```

Comment: Hmmm, if hour is 01..12 then, with your script, LAST_HOUR is 0..11, not 01..12. Even if your grep worked, you would miss some logs. => `SEARCH_STRING=$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-%I" -d "1 hour ago")`

Comment: Also note that since `%I` is zero-padded (`01..12`), you may run in to this issue: [Using bash “double paren” arithmetic expansion, math fails with leading zero](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19307/using-bash-double-paren-arithmetic-expansion-math-fails-with-leading-zero)

Answer (score 1):

With awk, it's  something like:

```
$ var=$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-%I:%M:%S %p" | awk -F[-:] '{print $4}') && echo $var
04
$ var=$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-%I:%M:%S %p" | awk -F[-:] '{print $4 - 1}') && echo $var
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Log file contains date format in 2017-03-15T08:00:23.698411Z format.
If this timing is in UTC which is 2017-03-15T08:00:23.698411Z(time and date is 08:00:23 and 2017-03-15) and you need to convert it in IST.
Use below command for last hour

`date -d '2017-03-15T08:00:23.698411Z last hours' -u +%s`

1489561223

`date -d @1489561223 +"%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S"`

2017/03/15-07:00:23

want to go back 2 hours ago,then use "2 hours ago" instead of "last hours".

Note:- I am running above command in linux server and my linux server timing is in UTC.If you want to run above command in IST linux server,then  you have to add another 5 hours 30 minutes(eg:- "6 hours 30 minutes ago" instead of "last hours").