# How to compare 09 to 11

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So I have a code that takes a part of a filename which is in date format and checks if that number is higher than 11.
All the files follow the same naming principal just with different names and dates. ->
example:

Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jonas.De Preter.s.ua_poging_2019-11-12
(note: this filename is a directory)

Here is my code that takes the last 2 numbers and compares them to 11 and if the number is higher than it creates a directory:

```
for d in ./*/*/; do
  [[ ! -d "$d" ]] && continue
  char=${d: -3}
  (( ${char%/} > 11 )) &&
  mkdir -p "$d"late_inzending
done
```

The problem I get is that when the date is less than 10 then it compares for example 09 with 11. And that gives me an error

09 > 11 --> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 679: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Not sure why you get that error but in the condition you can try this: `(( "10#${char%/}" > 11 ))`. With `10#` you force bash to use the value as a decimal/number.

Comment: Likely related: [Using bash "double paren" arithmetic expansion, math fails with leading zero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19307/using-bash-double-paren-arithmetic-expansion-math-fails-with-leading-zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by simply using sed.

```
#the string which I'm working with:
#Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jolien.Peters.s.ua_poging_2019-11-12

for d in ./*/*/; do
  char=${d: -3} #:Variable to get the last 2 numbers in this string(12/)
  x=${char%/} #:Variable to remove the invisible "/"
  y=$(echo $x | sed 's/^0*//')#:Incase there are leading zeros remove them
  echo $y
  (( "$y" > 11 )) && #Compare the numbers and if $y is bigger then make new directory
  mkdir -p "$d"late_inzending
done
```

Comment: Consider explaining your answer in more detail other than showing the code.